# To convert string datatype column to date datatype using pyspark

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have created a sample csv file with two columns- id,modified date column with datetime datatype.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ7ez.png).

I copied that csv file to azure blob storage and from their i mounted it onto azure databricks.

Now i am trying to convert that modifieddate column to date type, since csv file read everything in string format.
I had written following code :
**df= df.withColumn("date",df["modifieddate"].cast(DateType()))**

As a result i am getting null values as shown below.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJKye.png)

please anyone help me to solve this error and why does i am getting error

Comment: Do not post text as image. Also, what null value are you talking about ? The only reference to null here is that the column is nullable. It does not mean it is null.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing you are missing is the setting

`sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")`

and you have to specify the input date format as below :

`F.to_timestamp(F.col("modifieddate"), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')`
or

`F.to_timestamp(F.col("modifieddate"), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')`

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import dateutil.parser

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

### This is very important setting if you want legacy behaviour
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")

data1 = [
            ["1","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["2","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["3","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["4","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["5","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["6","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["7","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["8","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["9","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["10","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["11","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["12","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["13","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["14","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
            ["15","9/6/2023 17:51:23"],
        ]

df1Columns = ["id","modifieddate"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

### If 9/6/2023 means 2023-06-09
new_df = df1.withColumn("date", F.to_timestamp(F.col("modifieddate"), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
new_df.show()

# OR

## If 9/6/2023 means 2023-09-06
new_df2 = df1.withColumn("date", F.to_timestamp(F.col("modifieddate"), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
new_df2.show()
```

Output :

```
+---+-----------------+-------------------+
| id|     modifieddate|               date|
+---+-----------------+-------------------+
|  1|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
|  2|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
|  3|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
|  4|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
|  5|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
|  6|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
|  7|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
|  8|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
|  9|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
| 10|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
| 11|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
| 12|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
| 13|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
| 14|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
| 15|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-06-09 17:51:23|
+---+-----------------+-------------------+

+---+-----------------+-------------------+
| id|     modifieddate|               date|
+---+-----------------+-------------------+
|  1|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|  2|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|  3|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|  4|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|  5|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|  6|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|  7|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|  8|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
|  9|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
| 10|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
| 11|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
| 12|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
| 13|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
| 14|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
| 15|9/6/2023 17:51:23|2023-09-06 17:51:23|
+---+-----------------+-------------------+
```