# Convert string to timestamp in pyspark

Tags: string, pyspark, timestamp

I am trying to convert the date format mmddyyHHmmss(is a string data type in pyspark) to timestamp in pyspark. I tried the below code, but I am getting nulls.

```
date_string="09082023123456"
date_format = "MMddyyyyMMddHHmmss"
df = df.withColumn("timestamp_column", 
to_timestamp(df["date_string"], date_format))
```

Comment: why doing `df["date_string"]`? is `date_string` a column?

Comment: date_string is a column in my dataframe

Comment: You can adapt this answer of mine. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77052318/3238085

Comment: the format looks incorrect -- shouldn't it be `"MMddyyyyHHmmss"`?

Answer (score 0):

your format in `date_format` looks incorrect. you won't require the `MMdd` in the middle.

```py
spark.createDataFrame([('09082023123456',)], ['dt_str']). \
    withColumn('tm1', func.to_timestamp('dt_str', 'MMddyyyyMMddHHmmss')). \
    withColumn('tm2', func.to_timestamp('dt_str', 'MMddyyyyHHmmss')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +--------------+----+-------------------+
# |dt_str        |tm1 |tm2                |
# +--------------+----+-------------------+
# |09082023123456|null|2023-09-08 12:34:56|
# +--------------+----+-------------------+
```

`tm1` is using your format and `tm2` is using the corrected format.

Comment: I will check it. Thank you